# How to embed a button in input?

Tags: html, css, search, input

I have a search box in which there is a button and input for entering text. Please tell me how to embed this button in input, on the right. I know that the input is set to position: relative, and to the absolute button itself. But how to do further I can not understand. I apologize for the long class names.

```css
.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_ {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #000000;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 45px 0 20px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: RobotoCondensed;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #B72A20;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.search_result_message {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #159815;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_">
 
    <label class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_text">
    search
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit" placeholder="search">
    <input type="button" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button">
    <span class="search_result_message"></span>
   
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following css property to the class `.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button`,

```
position: absolute; 
right: 6%; 
top: 43%;
```

Snippet as follows,

```css
.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_ {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #000000;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 45px 0 20px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 6%; 
    top: 43%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: RobotoCondensed;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #B72A20;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.search_result_message {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #159815;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_">
  <div class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search">
    <div class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_text">
    search
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_edit" placeholder="search">
    <input type="button" class="middle_content_blog_content_blocks_search_button">
    <span class="search_result_message"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```